# Adding a Nested Form with JQuery "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL"

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, forms, nested-forms

I am using Rails 3 and JQuery and trying to have a nested form be appended into my main form on the click of a button.  Without the javascript, the form and nested forms work fine.  I want the nested form to only be added if a user clicks on the button.  They can also add many nested forms by clicking the button multiple times.

On another thread someone said to use an ajax call "The onclick is executing in the browser so you're not going to be able to use erb in it.  You'll want to make an ajax call (.load is a handy shortcut for this) to the server where you can render the partial using erb to get the html you need returned."

Does anyone know how I could do that or if I even should?

### My javascript file is as such..

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#add-family-button").click(function(){
    var form = "<div class='form-group col-xs-3'>
      <%= f.fields_for :users, @new_user do |ff| %>
        <%= label_tag :first_name %>
        <%= ff.text_field :first_name, placeholder: 'First Name' %>
        <%= label_tag :last_name %>
        <%= ff.text_field :last_name, placeholder: 'Last Name' %>
      <% end %>
    </div>";
        $("#child-forms-div").append(form);
    });
 });
```

### My form is

```
<%= form_for(@family) do |f| %>
  <form class = 'form-horizontal' role = 'form'>
    <div class='form-group'>
      <%= f.label :name %>
      <%= f.text_field :name, placeholder: @family.name %>
    </div>
    <button type="button" id="add-family-button" class="btn btn-warning">Add Family Member</button>

    <div id="child-forms-div" class='form-group'>
    </div>
    <div class='actions'>
      <%= f.submit %>
    </div>
  </form>
<% end %>
```

Jquery is working for all other functions.
The error is for javascript Line 3 which is

```
var form = "<div class='form-group col-xs-3'>
```

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating a multi-line string you need to place a \ at the end of each line. Otherwise, place your loop code all into one line.

Comment: I looped it all in one line and it is not showing on click but it is displayed as  

<%= f.fields_for :users, @new_user do |ff| %><%= label_tag :first_name %><%= ff.text_field :first_name, placeholder: 'First Name' %><%= label_tag :last_name %> ETC

The html divs are being read correctly but the ruby is not.